# Event Logger for Firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need an Add-on for Firefox to display every click events in Firefox console. I implemented event logger(https://github.com/azreda/Event-Logger-for-Firefox/tree/e4957a58f5c202964febc53b20a578ac05a348cf) for Firefox but it doesn't Display log events in console.Please help me how to display every click events in Firefox console and i need to send every click events to Server(Java Application).

Comment: Would you mind to add how you used it in your code? The more detail you can provide, the better for people to be able to answer.